# how use EOF stdin in C

Tags: c, stdin, scanf, feof

I need to input coordinates into an array until EOF is encountered, but something is wrong in my code.  I used ctrl+Z, ctrl+D

```
int main()
{
    int x[1000],y[1000];
    int n=0,nr=0,a,b,i;
    printf("Enter the coordinates:\n");
    while(scanf ( "%d %d ", &a, &b) == 2)
    {
     x[n]=a;
     y[n]=b;
     n++;
    }
    if (!feof(stdin))
    {
       printf("Wrong\n");
    }
    else
    {
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       printf("%d %d\n", x[i], y[i]);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is wrong always printed?

Answer (score 19):

I suggest using

```
while(!feof(stdin) && scanf ( "%d %d ", &a, &b) == 2)
```

and actually it is better to test [feof](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html) *after* (not before!) some input operation, so:

```
while (scanf("%d %d ", &a, &b) == 2 && !feof(stdin))
```

BTW, on many systems `stdin` is *line* buffered, at least with interactive terminals (but perhaps not when *stdin* is a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)), see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)

On Linux & POSIX you might consider reading every line with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or even with [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) if reading from the terminal, since `readline` offers editing abilities), then parsing that line with e.g. [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (perhaps also using `%n`) or [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Answer (score 3):

The only real problem that I see in your code is the extra spaces in the `scanf` format string. Those spaces tell `scanf` to consume whitespace character on the input, which makes `scanf` not return to your code until it hits a non-whitespace character (such as a letter, a number, punctuation, or EOF).

The result is that after typing two numbers and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in DOS/Windows) *twice* before your program escapes the `while` loop.