# How do I get this program to stop execution after I run it for the first time?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*input: 3 4 -5 2 6 1 -2 0
output:12 3 -10 1 6 0*/
int main(){
    int a,b;
    int flag=0;
    while(scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)!=EOF){
        if(b!=0){
            if(flag==0)printf("%d",a*b);
            else printf(" %d",a*b);
            printf(" %d",b-1);
            flag=1;//if b==0,this loop performs nothing.
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)printf("0 0");
    return 0;
}
```

This is a program that takes a polynomial(the first number of a pair is the coefficient,the second is the power) and compute its derivative in the same fashion.However,this program doesn't give me the intended result when I input 6 0 or 0 0,the result should be 0 0 in both cases.
Additionally,I intend for this program to stop after one execution(one press of "Enter".How should I do that without changing entirely the code?

Comment: Try `Ctrl + Z` and `Enter`, or `F6`

Comment: Or `Ctrl + D` on Linux

Comment: Or `Ctrl + C` (at least on Linux).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how use EOF stdin in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094702/how-use-eof-stdin-in-c)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `Ctrl + C` will trigger a `SIGKILL`

Comment: @gkhaos isn't CTRL-C `SIGINT`? Because I can handle a CTRL-C signal, while I believe `SIGKILL` is just a forceful kill.

Comment: when your conditions are met, I would simply `break`, or you could test `flag` _first_ in the `while` condition: `while (!flag && scanf(...`

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 indeed, anyway it does not send an `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Change `while(scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)!=EOF)` to `while(scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)==2)`.

Comment: that's actually my original approach ,still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Read full line via `fgets()`
2. Parse the line via `sscanf()`
3. During the parsing, use `%n` to read the number of bytes consumed and proceed to next token

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*input: 3 4 -5 2 6 1 -2 0
output:12 3 -10 1 6 0*/
int main(){
    char line[8192];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)!=NULL){
        int pos=0, delta;
        int a,b;
        int flag=0;
        while(sscanf(line+pos,"%d %d%n",&a,&b,&delta)==2){
            pos+=delta;
            if(b!=0){
                if(flag==0)printf("%d",a*b);
                else printf(" %d",a*b);
                printf(" %d",b-1);
                flag=1;//if b==0,this loop performs nothing.
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)printf("0 0");
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```